# mongodb query nest $or inside an "AND"

Tags: mongodb

in my document, i have two fields:

{
    rank: null / 0 - 1000,
    age: null / 0 - 1000
}

I want to make a query that look like this

```
(rank == null || 50 < rank && rank < 80) && (age == null || 27 < age && age < 39)
```

my question is, how do I express this query in a single mongodb find query?

I can easily write

```
Gamer.find({rank: {$gt: 50, $lt: 80}, age: {$gt: 27, $lt: 39}})
```

But how do I deal with the case where the gamer did not have an age or rank set?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $exists for this query. The query would look like.

```
    Gamer.find({$or:[{rank: { $gt: 50, $lt: 80}}, {rank: {$exists: false}}]}, 
{$or:[{age: { $gt: 27, $lt: 39}}, {age: {$exists: false}}]});
```

it will check if rank exists and fulfill the condition then return the data.

Comment: My point is that, if they don't exist, I want to find them too. so EITHER they don't exist, OR they fall in range.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid query. Your second $or is passed as a second object to the query, which is used for projection and not querying..

Comment: Actually all I needed was your answer, slightly tweaked, use explicit $and to chain everything together

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is what I needed

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator

```
Gamer.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { rank: {$gt: 50, $lt: 80} }, {rank: {$exists: false}} ] },
        { $or : [ { age: {$gt: 27, $lt: 39} }, {age: {$exists: false}} ] }
    ]
} )
```